# how to clear data of a table before each ajax call

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

Table data is not cleared after each ajax call. New data is appended below the previous data

$('#show_data').remove(); 
I have tried this but its not working

**View**

```
<table id="example2" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Title</th>
                            <th>Description</th>
                            <th>Date</th>
                            <th>Time</th>
                            <th>Action</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody id="show_data">

                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

Script

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        //Date picker
        $('#datepicker').datepicker({
            autoclose: true,
            format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
        });

        $("#datepicker").attr("autocomplete", "off");


    $(document).on('submit','#myform',function(){
        event.preventDefault();
        var date = $('#datepicker').val();
        console.log(date);
        $('#show_data').remove();
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"<?php echo base_url().'admin/Dashboard/get_blog'; ?>",
            data:{date:date},
            dataType: "json",
            success:function(data) {
                console.log(data[0].blog_id);
                let i;

                for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){

                    $('#show_data').append('<tr><td>' + data[i].article_name + '</td>' +
                        '<td>' + data[i].description + '</td>' +
                        '<td>' + data[i].date + '</td>' +
                        '<td>' + data[i].time + '</td>' +
                        '</tr>');
                }
            },
            error: function() {
                alert("oops...");
            },

        });
    });
 });

</script>
```

**Present Output**

Input-> 2019-05-25 -> Submit

Output-> Data 1
         Data 2

Input-> 2019-05-24 -> Submit

Output-> Data 1
         Data 2
         Data 3

**Expected Output**

Input-> 2019-05-25 -> Submit

Output-> Data 1
         Data 2

Input-> 2019-05-24 -> Submit

Output-> Data 3

Comment: Try this `$('#form_id').trigget('reset');`

Comment: @ Danish Ali `$('#form_id').trigger('reset');` will only clear the input fields in the form not the table contents.

Comment: @Kallol Medhi Try `$('#show_data').empty();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because you append your response to previous data. Try this way

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"<?php echo base_url().'admin/Dashboard/get_blog'; ?>",
    data:{date:date},
    dataType: "json",
    success:function(data) {
        console.log(data[0].blog_id);
        let i;

        let html= '';

        for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){

            html += '<tr><td>' + data[i].article_name + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + data[i].description + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + data[i].date + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + data[i].time + '</td>' +
                '</tr>');
        }

        $('#show_data').html(html);
    },
    error: function() {
        alert("oops...");
    },

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try change code

```
$('#show_data').remove();
```

to

```
$('#show_data').empty();
```

`empty()` function will clear content of the element. Docs is here https://api.jquery.com/empty/